# How to make field obey "scale" using activerecord and postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm storing a simple price figure in a PostgreSQL column using ActiveRecord, like so:

```
  t.decimal :base_price, precision: 9, scale: 2
```

Everything looks accurate in the actual data; if I store a value like "5.50", it's there as "5.50". However, when using ActiveModelSerializers, it always gets spit out as "5.5", which is expected, I just want to format it as currency by default. How can I accomplish this?

```
2.1.4 :004 > c.base_price
 => #<BigDecimal:7fd3739900e0,'0.55E1',18(18)> 
2.1.4 :005 > c.base_price.to_i
 => 5 
2.1.4 :006 > c.base_price.to_f
 => 5.5
```

At the moment, I've got a custom method on my Serializer that makes sure of this, but I feel like there may be a better, more Rails-y way...

```
def price
  "%.2f" % object.base_price
end
```

Comment: You got it right, the only way is to get the float formatted as a string. The default formatting for floats in ruby omits trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up using formatting in my Serailizer like so:

```
def price
  "%.2f" % object.base_price
end
```

but, as I am using Ember Data in an Ember.js project, I also added a transform to my project:

```
// transforms/currency.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

var format = function(number) {
  return parseFloat(number, 10).toFixed(2);
}

export default DS.Transform.extend({

  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return format(serialized);
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return format(deserialized);
  }

});
```

Then in my DS.Model:

```
  basePrice: DS.attr('currency')
```

This effectively formats the float as I needed on the client-side as well.